# Can't we use a single variable in three different module by making it global in python

Tags: python, global-variables

I am pretty new at programming. 
I have three files,
first one is "main.python", 
second one is "driver.python",
third one is "global_var.python" which is only used to intialise global variables.

main.python

```
import global_var
import driver
global_var.init()
driver.fun()
print(shinchan)
```

driver.python

```
import global_var
def fun():
   shinchan ="hello python"
```

global_var.python

```
def init():
   global shinchan
```

upon running this I am getting error

```
  File "main.py", line 13, in <module>
  print(shinchan)
  NameError: name 'shinchan' is not defined
```

I understand that in driver.python, python is creating altogether a new variable "shinchan" which has nothing to do with the global variable "shinchan" defined in "global_var.python", which I am trying to implement.

can't we use same variable in these three different files.

please help me out here.

Comment: `shinchan` is global to the `global_var` module. To access it in other modules, use the name `global_var.shinchan` (after importing `global_var`). In `driver.py` for example, do `global.var.shinchan = "hello python"`

Answer (score 0):

#### Accessing the variable

If you want to access `shinchan` in `main.py`, you need either change the import statement or reference it as an attribute of `global_var`.

So either change the import to

```
from global_var import shinchan
```

or change the call to

```
print(global_var.shinchan)
```

You probably don't want to have to call `global_var.init()` before you can access `global_var`, so what you probably want to do is this:

global_var.py

```
shinchan = '' # or whatever you want it to be initially
```

#### Setting the variable

```
global_var.shinchan = 'hello world'
```

But you probably don't want to do this.  Global variables get messy fast, and that's why you should try to avoid them at all costs.

#### How you probably want do this

If you want to get information from `driver.py` and store it in a variable in `main.py`, you should get the data you want from a function.  So something like this:

main.py

```
import driver
shinchan = 'hi'
shinchan = driver.getNewShinchan()
```

driver.py

```
def getNewShinchan():
    return 'hello world'
```

Comment: One pitfall in the `from global_var import shinchan` style of import is that now we have `shinchan` in more than one module. Initially the various `shinchan`s point to the same object, but if you want to reassign that name, it will only be assigned in the module where the assignment occurs. The names in the other modules still refer to the old value. Things get out of sync very quick. To avoid such problems, I suggest that every variable have a home module and you always access it through the full module name.